# Creating link to file location on network in confluence

Tags: windows, confluence

On confluence I want to create a link that links to:

P:\myFolder\folder, where P is mapped to a network share.

Just putting in "P:\myFolder\folder" doesn't work. Any ideas?

(Assuming I cannot put in the full network path).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

typically what would work is

```
file:///p:/myFolder/folder/
```

If there are spaces in the name like 'My Documents' you can surround the link with [ ]

```
[file:///p:/my Folder/folder/]
```

Of course you can also add an alias:

```
[The Folder|file:///p:/my Folder/folder/]
```

I just tested a variation of this and it seemed to work.

```
[file:///\\\\servername/share/folder/file.ext] works in IE (note two back slashes in front for the server name)
```

Comment: What about UNC paths?  Using `[file:///\\server\path\file name.ext]`, I get "not valid link markup".  Ditto if I replace the backslashes with forward slashes.

Comment: Does this solution work with linking to FTP as well? ftp::///user:pass@LinkToFTPServer.com/foldername ??

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir Alexiev writes, the browser might need some setting up. Firefox and Opera do not allow opening links to local files. This is for security purposes. 
Have a look at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Linking+to+local+file+under+Firefox (This page is located within the JIRA documentation, but the information is not JIRA-specific.)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Windows 7 under Firefox 24.5:

```
\\\\servername\share\folder\
```

translates to:

```
file://///servername/share/folder
```

That is 5 forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

no need to use `file:\\\;`
just put as

```
<a href="localhost/V1.mp4">download</a>
```

where ***localhost*** is your server name;

Answer (score 0):

You can setup *Shortcut Links** (*Browse>Admin>Shortcut Links*) to make this easier. Then you can write e.g. `[myFolder/folder@P]`

You may also need to take care for your browser to open the links. That depends by browser.